# Can a cleric of life use necromancy?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, necromancy

Necromancy is a spell that uses negative energy. Spells learned by clerics of life use positive energy (and there is a exclusive spell from clerics that is from the necromancy school).

So, would a cleric of life lose his spells because they used/use necromancy?

Comment: “Necromancy” isn’t a spell at all, it’s an entire school of magic encompassing many different spells. All spells that revolve around life—adding to it (healing), taking it away (harming), restoring it when lost entirely (resurrecting), or replacing it with an artificial construct (undead-animating) are under the necromancy school. Some of those (the healing spells) are entirely appropriate for a life cleric. Others (the undead-animating ones) seem to be what you’re referring to, and could be more dubious. Do you perhaps mean *animate dead* and similar spells?

Comment: @KRyan Strictly speaking, that's not true: Most healing spells fall under Evocation (*Cure Wounds*, *Healing Word*, *Prayer of Healing*, etc.), or Abjuration (*Lesser/Greater Restoration*, *Remove Curse*, *Dispel Magic*), with a tiny number that show up under Transmutation (*Regeneration*). It's really only the "bring back to life" spells that are classified as Necromancy, or some kinds of "deal damage and bring back health", like *Life Transference* or *Vampiric Touch*.

Comment: A lot of this sounds like terms and mechanics from previous editions of D&D. Are you new to 5e coming from one of these older editions?

Answer (score 11):

## There is no rule against a Life Cleric using Necromancy spells

If there were any such restriction, it would be specified in the Life Cleric subclass description.

## Some of the spells Life Clerics gain as part of their Domain are themselves Necromancy spells

It might seem counterintuitive depending on how you interpret these spells, but spells like *Raise Dead* or *Revivify* ([after Errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf)) come from the Necromancy school of magic. This in spite of the fact that their sole purpose is to bring a dead character back to life—and not to "undeath" like a zombie, but full proper life. By the laws of the universe, as written in the 5th edition Player's Handbook, bringing a dead soul back to life is considered a kind of Necromancy magic (or Transmutation, if you're a Druid casting *Reincarnation* to bring someone back to life).

All Life Clerics, once they reach the appropriate levels, gain these two spells (among other spells) as spells they always have prepared. If Life Clerics had a restriction against casting Necromancy spells, then it would be nonsensical that this domain would provide these spells to them for free.

Comment: Revivify is actually a conjuration based spell. Great explanation though.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that 5th edition rules do not refer to positive/negative energy, neither in spell descriptions or cleric abilities. Hence such things are not a consideration.

Comment: @PJRZ That's not entirely true: spells like *Negative Energy Flood* are rather explicit about using "ribbons of Negative Energy" to effect its damage/healing. The spell *Heal* also describes its effect as a "surge of Positive Energy". So while it is true that 5e has stepped back from grounding every single effect in those terms, it still exists in the flavor/names of many 5e spells.

Comment: @Xirema: Ah, I didn't even notice that. Other healing spells don't mention positive energy in the same way - even Mass Heal which just says "healing energy".  Seems a bit of a throwback in the fluff text (although I know that officially there is no such thing as 'fluff' text)!

Answer (score 4):

### Cleric have spells from the necromancy school

Clerics with the Life Domain actually get a Necromancy Domain spell at 9th level, Raise Dead. If that is granted to you by your god, they shouldn't take away your spells if you cast a spell of the Necromancy school as long as you are following what they are supposed to embody and their rules.

Gentle Repose (2d level, necromancy school) prevents the dead from becoming undead.

> You touch a corpse or other remains. For the duration, the target is
>   protected from decay and can’t become undead.

That spell prevents the basic premise of necromancy.

Comment: Leading with only "No" in the title may seem a bit confusing considering the title question was "Can a cleric of life use necromancy?" followed by "Would a cleric of life lose his spells because used/use necromancy?". It does become clear by reading the rest of the answer but maybe the title could be more complete.

Comment: Perrin, thought I'd flesh out your original point.  If edited in the wrong direction, by all means revert.

Comment: No by all means, flesh it out. I couldn't think of a way to flesh it out so I just put a basic answer. Thanks for the help.